# Using "Oblivion" color scheme from gedit in Kate

Tags: gedit, themes, kate

I like gedit's color scheme *Oblivion* a lot.
Is there a way to use the same color scheme in Kate text editor?

I know that configuration files for color scheme for gedit and Kate aren't compatible. I wonder if someone already adapted *Oblivion* scheme for Kate.

Thanks

Comment: Is this your forum post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10296717 if so seems like some one has got a solution for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10296717) posted by [Allan](https://askubuntu.com/users/6450/allan):

Put the following in the file `~/.kde/share/config/kateschemarc`:

```
[Oblivion]
Color Background=46,52,54
Color Highlighted Bracket=255,255,153
Color Highlighted Line=68,76,77
Color Icon Bar=234,233,232
Color Line Number=0,0,0
Color MarkType1=255,255,0
Color MarkType2=255,0,0
Color MarkType3=255,255,0
Color MarkType4=255,0,255
Color MarkType5=160,160,164
Color MarkType6=0,255,0
Color MarkType7=255,0,0
Color Selection=136,138,132
Color Spelling Mistake Line=255,0,0
Color Tab Marker=133,133,133
Color Template Background=204,204,204
Color Template Editable Placeholder=204,255,204
Color Template Focused Editable Placeholder=102,255,102
Color Template Not Editable Placeholder=255,204,204
Color Word Wrap Marker=118,122,124
Font=DejaVu Sans Mono,8,-1,2,50,0,0,0,0,0
```

Note, that due to different syntax highlighting, this might not be an 1:1 adoption of Gedit's theme.

Comment: it helped, I had to export and re-import with new name, to make minor changes and it worked perfectly, thx!