# Change color scheme in Kate

Tags: kate, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking to change the color scheme in Kate to something else (e.g Solarized, Zenburn, etc).

I tried the instructions found in [*Using “Oblivion” color scheme from Gedit in Kate*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19005/using-oblivion-color-scheme-from-gedit-in-kate), but nothing changed when I closed and reopened Kate.

What should I do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, it's easy with GUI:

1. Open Kate → Settings → Configure Kate... → Editor Component → Fonts & Colors
2. Choose the one you want.  For custom one use: New...

   It's also possible to export it. Edit it as text then import it again.